# How to render the chart in VS2017 React+Redux template?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-2017, react-redux, dc.js, timeserieschart

I'm trying to build chart using dc.js using React_Redux template provided in VS2017. I have created a separate component (SeriesChart.tsx) for this and added charting specific code in componentDidMount() method of the component. Below is the code of SeriesChart.tsx

```
    // A '.tsx' file enables JSX support in the TypeScript compiler, 
// for more information see the following page on the TypeScript wiki:
// https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JSX

import * as React from 'react';
import { Link, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { ApplicationState } from '../store';
import * as CounterStore from '../store/Counter';
import * as WeatherForecasts from '../store/WeatherForecasts';

import * as d3 from 'd3';
import * as dc from 'dc';
import * as crossfilter from 'crossfilter';
import { scaleTime, scaleLinear } from 'd3-scale';
import * as d3Time from 'd3-time-format';

export class SeriesChart extends React.Component<{}, {}> {

    componentDidMount() {
        var chart = dc.seriesChart("lineChart");

        var data =  [
  {
    "Time": "19-Jan-2018 11:24:49.000 UTC",
    "Speed": 0.634
  },
  {
    "Time": "19-Jan-2018 11:24:52.000 UTC",
    "Speed": 1.435
  },
  {
    "Time": "19-Jan-2018 11:24:53.000 UTC",
    "Speed": 0.789
  },
  {
    "Time": "19-Jan-2018 11:24:54.000 UTC",
    "Speed": 1.876
  }
];

        var mycrossfilter = crossfilter(data);

        //var format = d3.time.format("%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S");
        var formatTime = d3Time.timeParse("%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S");

        data.forEach(function (d) {
            var newDate = new Date(d.Time);
            var stringDate = "" + newDate.getFullYear() + "," + newDate.getMonth() + "," + newDate.getDate() + "," + newDate.getHours() + "," + newDate.getMinutes() + "," + newDate.getSeconds() + "";
            var formattedString = formatTime(stringDate);
            d.Time = formattedString.toLocaleString();
        });

        var dateDim = mycrossfilter.dimension(function (d) { return [d.Time, d.Speed] });

        var minDate = dateDim.bottom(1)[0].Time;
        var maxDate = dateDim.top(1)[0].Time;

        var minDateInDate = new Date(minDate);
        var maxDateInDate = new Date(maxDate);

        var minSpeed = dateDim.bottom(1)[0].Speed;
        var maxSpeed = dateDim.top(1)[0].Speed;

        var group = dateDim.group().reduceCount();

        chart
            .width(650)
            .height(350)
            .dimension(dateDim)
            .x(scaleTime().domain([minDateInDate, maxDateInDate]))
            .y(scaleLinear().domain([1.8, maxSpeed]))
            .renderlet(function (chart) {
                chart.selectAll("circle")
                    .style("fill", "grey")
                    .style("fill-opacity", 1)
                    .on("mousemove", null)
                    .on("mouseout", null)                     
            })
            .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
            .renderVerticalGridLines(true)
            .group(group)
            .xAxisLabel("Time")
            .yAxisLabel("EngineSpeed")
            .brushOn(false)
            .seriesAccessor(
            function (d) {
                return d.value;
            })
            .keyAccessor(function (d) {
                return d.key[0];
            })
            .valueAccessor(function (d) {
                return d.key[1];
            })
            .ordinalColors(['blue']);

        //chart.xAxis();
        chart.render();

    }

    public render() {
        return <div >
        </div>;
    }
}
```

Now I want to know how to render this chart in render() method of the component so that chart gets rendered properly. In plain html syntax we define the element in following way.

```
<div id = "lineChart"></div>
```

and this will be the input to the seriesChart() function as below.

```
var chart = dc.seriesChart('#lineChart');
```

But in my case, I'm not getting how do I establish that connection in react component (between componentdidMount() and render() methods).

Can someone please help.